# Validate user supplied relative file system path

Tags: perl, filesystems

I want to allow users to navigate through a section of my web servers file system, ensuring they are unable to access parent directories. This section is dynamic, therefore cannot be defined.

I believe my best option would be to append a user supplied relative path onto a constant base path i.e.:

```
use Cwd;
use CGI qw/:standard/;
use File::Spec::Functions;

my $base_path = catfile( getcwd, 'base' );
my $rel_path  = param('rel_path');
my $full_path = catfile( $base_path, $rel_path );

print $full_path;
```

What validation / cleanup must I perform on the user supplied relative path / full path. I am not 100% certain of the different ways the user could manipulate the relative path and violate the integrity of the system and application.

Thanks,

Chris

Answer (score 0):

Just check if $full_path has $base_path in front.

```
unless ( $full_path =~ m{^$base_path} ) { $full_path = $base_path; }
```

Or explicitly forbid double point in the $rel_path:

```
$rel_path = '' if $rel_path =~ /\.\./;
```

Comment: Because the base path placement is hard coded, your condition will never be true. It also means I shouldn't ever have to explicitly define the full path as the base path?

Comment: Hackers usually check paths in CGI parameters with paths like '../../../../../../../../etc/passwd'.

Comment: very good point, segments of upper working directory i.e. /../, would have to be filtered, otherwise the user could easily gain access to prohibited parent paths.